# Getting the value of an h6 toString

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm writing a test where I need to get the value of an h6 element to string so I can throw it into a query.

I have tried the following:

```
WebElement trackingNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/h6"));
System.out.println(trackingNumber.getText().toString());
```

This gives me nothing at all.

```
WebElement trackingNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/h6"));
System.out.println(trackingNumber.toString());
```

This gives me gobbledygook. `[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (03665d0a-ebf8-164f-bf06-e13f4590e452)] -> xpath: /html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/h6]`

```
WebElement trackingNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/h6"));
System.out.println(trackingNumber.getAttribute("value"));
```

This returns `null`

When I run the test I know that the value I am looking for is there and am just wondering why I am getting a `null` value.

Comment: I do not think `/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/h6` identifies the node you think it identifies.  Use Firebug to confirm that the XPath is correct.

Comment: Yes the tracking number is displayed and yes the XPath is correct. I just cannot seem to get the value to print out to my console at the moment, want to make sure I have it printing out to the console, before I try to throw it into a query.

Comment: are you sure the html file is well-formed? is it xhtml? or html?

Comment: The html for the element is: `<h6 class="tracking-number muted">2013-07-001-D</h6>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(trackingNumber.getAttribute("textContent"));
```

However, this should behave the same with `getText()`, so I doubt if this is gonna work.

Also try change your locator:

```
WebElement trackingNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h6[@class='tracking-number muted']"));
System.out.println(trackingNumber.getText());
```

Comment: `System.out.println(trackingNumber.getAttribute("textContent"));` worked just fine, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
WebElement trackingNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/h6"));
System.out.println(trackingNumber.getText());
```

There is no need to add "toString()" because getText returns string value already.